# Visual Studio 2005 Can't find System assemblies

Tags: visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I have Visual Studio 2008 installed on my machine, but I haven't used it.  I did open a dummy project and make sure that version 2.0 is the .NET Framework version I am using, since it is the one that suddenly doesn't work for me.

Here's the warning message I get when I am trying to open an existing Windows 2005 project.

"Namespace or type specified in the project level Imports 'System.Data' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found."

All of the basic System, System.Data, System.XML assemblies show up in a new project with the yellow exclamation point warning.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?  Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by downloading and re-installing .NET 2.0 on your system.

Comment: This did work, but I still think there is a Source Safe issue involved somewhere, as my new projects don't have the issue anymore, but the ones in source safe do.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the project references and make sure that you have System.Data added to the project.